# How do I save my Tomato plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, tomatoes

Recently my tomato plant seems dying. The leaves from the bottom are drying up. The leaves have turn curly (some inward, some outward).

I water the plant everyday morning. I live in Ahmedabad, recently the heat is rising, and I think the sun light is too much for the plant, so I am covering the plant with cloth in day time so it does not get excessive sunlight. Is this correct to do?

Also, how do I save the plant? Any help is appreciated.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]

Answer (score 2):

I have only accomplished one season of tomato growing, but I feel fairly confident in saying that the problem is over-watering made worse by the pot and soil. I have included several links detailing other potential reasons for the wilting and yellow leaves. I would think as you work to remedy the water situation it would become increasingly clear if over-watering is the problem or if it is something else.

There are many reasons that a tomato plant can have yellow leaves on its lower branches. Simply a few yellow leaves on the lower branch aren't indication of a major problem, but it is the fact that the rest of your plant looks wilted that is troubling.

When a plant is waterlogged, it doesn't get the oxygen that it needs. If it becomes bad enough to get root rot, then it will not be able to absorb water and nutrients through its roots.

The reasons I think you are over-watering the plant:

1. You mentioned watering every day
2. It looks like you have clay soil and it is very wet (clay = poor drainage - I have clay soil too...)
3. Pots can make life more challenging when it comes to watering. I'm guessing you do not have a drain hole at the bottom of the pot since your soil looks so wet

I also think that your plant will do much better in a bigger pot. I would get a larger pot with a drainage hole. If you are able to make a self-wicking bucket as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8aE9nd8D4s), I absolutely recommend going that route- you'll save yourself the headache of wondering if you've watered the right amount, and your plant will be so much happier.

Next, I would try to get compost or better soil to put in with your plant. The water will drain better and I believe your plant will have an easier time absorbing nutrients. You could also put mulch on top of the soil to keep the soil cooler and retain the moisture in the mulch. And of course, if you don't do the self-wicking system, do not water as often.

Sites which detail common problems associated with yellow leaves:

[Symptoms of Over-watering Tomato Plants](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/signs-symptoms-overwatering-tomatoes-24302.html)

[Bottom Tomato Plant Leaves Turning Yellow](https://greenupside.com/tomato-plants-bottom-leaves-turning-yellow-causes-fix/)

[Reasons for Wilting Tomato Plants](https://www.gardeningchannel.com/tomato-plants-wilting-explanations/)

[Watering Tips for Tomato Plants](https://dengarden.com/gardening/How-to-water-Tomato-plants-the-right-way)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer @Kar. I think I am watering the plant in expected quantity. I shall try reducing the water. My pot does have a drainage at very bottom. I shall definitely try all the links you have shared. Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: You are welcome. As you know, there are factors which can affect the amount one should water the plant and the recommendation should be a loose guide. I believe you that you are watering the plant the recommended amount. But that were if the plant were in good soil. Clay will hold the water for a longer period of time and it will stay wet so adjustments should be made. It could be the problem is one of the diseases listed in the articles, but it is easier to address a soil/watering problem so I would start there. I found a few more articles that may be helpful.

Comment: I forgot that the speed of watering is important for clay soil. I poke holes in the caps of water bottles and put the bottle upside down so the water slowly drips down into the clay.  1)https://www.gardenguides.com/121597-water-clay-soil.html  2)https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/soil_type_influences_irrigation_strategy